# Teamcity not uploading green builds

Tags: git, version-control, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Teamcity pulls from my git account fine, builds and runs tests and exits.

The end of the log says:

```
Publishing internal artifacts
    [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
Build finished
```

My VCS route is set to pull from the master branch and to push to a "healthy" branch, however nothing is pushed up.

Comment: Pushing to Git seems like something you would need to configure (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326487/teamcity-on-successful-build-push-to-git-repo , http://www.hamishgraham.net/post/Enabling-TeamCity-Push-to-GitHub.aspx ). How have you enabled it?

Comment: What do you mean "push to a healthy branch"? How is your VCS Root / Build Steps setup to do that?