# Git Push from TeamCity hangs the build

Tags: git, teamcity, push

I think I now tried about everything that is to be found on the web around "git push" from within a TeamCity build

I tried this: [TeamCity: On successful build push to Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326487/teamcity-on-successful-build-push-to-git-repo)

and this:

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5510674

and many variations on this. Every git operation (git add, commit,...) works perfectly but git push always hangs the build. If I do exactly the same in the command line, it works perfectly. And btw Git does not need passwords or anything.

I would love to solve this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the agent logs and figure out the command  that is running as part of the git push. Once you get the command, login to the box where the agent is running and run the same command (You need to do this with the same userid with which  the agent is running). This will give you the actual error as to why your git push is hanging